# Use class content inside REGEX

Tags: regex, matlab

I want to parse a nested structure like this one in MATLAB :

```
structure NAME_PART_1
    Some content

    block NAME_PART_2
        Some other content
    end NAME_PART_2

    block NAME_PART_3
        subblock NAME_PART_4
            Some content++
        end NAME_PART_4
    end NAME_PART_3

end NAME_PART_1

structure           
    NAME_PART_5

end        NAME_PART_5
```

First, I would like to extract the content of each structure. It's quite easy because a structure content is always between "structure NAME" and "end NAME".

So, I would like to use regex. But I don't know in advance what the structure name will be.

So, I wrote my regex like this :

```
\bstructure\s+([\w.-]*)((?:\s|.)*)\bend\b\s+XXXX
```

But, I don't know by what I should replace "XXXX", in order to "reference" the content of the first class of this regex. But is that even possible?

Comment: This content looks nested to me, in which case pure ragex might not be the best solution.  You may want to write a parser here.

Comment: You can reference the first matched group with `\1`. See [this documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#btrvwd4) for more info.

Comment: Ty @Adam :) I didn't know this flag.

Comment: you can do something like this mate https://regex101.com/r/wR8VQD/1/

Comment: @graille `\1`  is not a flag. it is called backreference

Comment: @graille Does that solve your problem completely? If so, I'll make an answer for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex:

```
structure\s+([\w.-]+)\s*((?:(?!end\s+\1)[\s\S])*)end\s+\1
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kspJo4/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `structure` - matches `structure`
- `\s+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a white-space
- `([\w.-]+)` - matches 1+ occurrences of either a word character or a `.` or a `-`. This sub-match which contains the structure name is captured in Group 1.
- `\s*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a white-space
- `((?:(?!end\s+\1)[\s\S])*)` - **[Tempered Greedy Token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/5331061)** - Matches 1+ occurrences of any character `[\s\S]` which does not start with the sequence `end` followed by Group 1 contents `\1` i.e, structure name. This sub-match is captured in Group 2 which contains the contents of the structure
- `end\s+\1` - matches the word `end` followed by 1+ white-spaces followed by Structure Name contained in Group 1 `\1`.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from making use of a backreference `\1` to refer what is captured, you might replace the alternation in the capturing group `((?:\s|.)*)` with matching a newline followed by 0+ characters and repeat that while capturing it `((?:\n.*)+)`

Also you might omit the word boundary after end `end\b\s+` as 1+ whitespace characters is what follows after end and instead add a word boundary at the end so that `\1` is not part of a larger match.

```
\bstructure\s+([\w.-]+)((?:\n.*)+)\bend\s+\1\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i2ktCK/1/)

**Explanation**

- `\bstructure\s+` Match structure followed by 1+ whitespace chars
- `([\w.-]+)` Capture in a group repeating 1+ times any of the listed chars
- `(` Capturing group

  - `(?:\n.*)+` Match newline followed by 0+ times any char except a newline
- `)` Close capturing group
- `\bend` Match end
- `\s+\1\b` Match 1+ times a whitespace char followed by a backreference to group 1 and end with a word boundary.